# Mouse Directly over element in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I want to get the mouse directly over element. In WPF, I can get the mouse over element by using the below code

```
DependencyObject el = Mouse.DirectlyOver as DependencyObject;
```

But Mouse is not available in silverlight. Hence I have used `VisualTreeHelper` like below code

```
var el = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(point, this.grid);
```

The above code returns collection of `UIElement`. But I want only the mouse Directly over element like we get in WPF. So Please suggest a way to get Mouse Directly over element in Silverlight.

Comment: I really wonder if there is a way. I could not change mouse icon for SL previously. SL is a bit restricted.

Comment: I'm pretty positive you can get the mouse position but that you can't explicitly set the position due to security restrictions in SL.

Answer (score 0):

[FindElementInHostCoordinates documentatiom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states you could use first (topmost) element in returned collection (e.g. by using `FirstOrDefault()` linq extension)